# How should the [penetration-test] tag be used?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see a lot of questions tagged with [penetration-test](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penetration-test) that in my opinion has nothing to do with pen testing other than that the OP came up with the quesiton while doing a pen test.

Some random examples:

- [Is it possible to transfer malware/viruses through a KVM Switch, from one computer to others?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137308/is-it-possible-to-transfer-malware-viruses-through-a-kvm-switch-from-one-comput)
- [How do I brute-force a WPA-2 wifi with Aircrack-ng in Kali Linux?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/136920/how-do-i-brute-force-a-wpa-2-wifi-with-aircrack-ng-in-kali-linux)
- [File exchange over DNS Tunneling](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/136356/file-exchange-over-dns-tunneling)

I think this might be a bad use of the tag. It is sort of like having a [study-for-a-test](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/study-for-a-test) tag for questions that came up while the OP is preparing for an exam. Tags should be about the question, not the reason the OP asked it.

The current excerpt is this:

> An attempt to penetrate a system's security in an effort to evaluate the protections in place.

So, my questions are:

- Am I correct that the tag should not be used for questions like these?
- Should I remove it when I see it in the wrong place?
- Could someone suggest a better excerpt that explains how the tag should be used, instead of just defining the term?
- If we used this tag correctly, how much of it would be left?