# Establish [bug-bounty] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed there is no tag for [bug bounty programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_bounty_program). Does it make sense to establish a tag like `[bug-bounty]` that covers questions about vulnerability reward programs (like [the one Google runs](https://bughunter.withgoogle.com/)) and bug hunting on platforms like [HackerOne](https://hackerone.com/) or [Bugcrowd](https://bugcrowd.com/)?

I am tempted to create a category for questions like these:

- [Why do several bug bounties ignore user enumeration?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124653/why-do-several-bug-bounties-ignore-user-enumeration)
- [How to work effectively to win bug-bounties?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59389/how-to-work-effectively-to-win-bug-bounties)
- [Worst-case scenario OPEN URL REDIRECTION and why google not covering it in bug bounty](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67939/worst-case-scenario-open-url-redirection-and-why-google-not-covering-it-in-bug-b)

Comment: If there is nothing similar or potentially synonymous - I say go for it! That is a sensible tag. P.s. please try to flll out the tag wiki / guidance, so that it doesn't get thrown on any "bug"-related question...

Comment: Nice that you created the tag! And good usage guidance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree it could be a useful tag, **but we need to make sure it is used in the right way.** There is a high risk that it gets [the same problem as the penetration test tag](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/how-should-the-penetration-test-tag-be-used) - it is used for question about anything, that just happend to arise while the poster was working on a bug bounty.

To combat that we need good and clear usage guidance, preferably that explicitly explains how to use the tag and not just what the words mean. Maybe something like this (just a suggestion, I am sure it can be improved):

> Use for question about the design and workings of bug bounty programs. Do not use for questions about bugs in general, or for questions that is not explicitly about the program itself.

But still, in my humble opinion it would be a useful tag, so I say create it!

Comment: I happen to agree with this. However, if `bug-bounty` tag was established, it would attract a lot of users who are to ask specifically about how to write a report, why they rejected their bug's & couple more off-topic which isn't related to core penetration testing or information security as a whole. How does one deal with that?

Comment: @ShritamBhowmick The tag is already created. :-) I don't think "how to write a report" or "why was I rejected" are necesaraly off topic. But others might disagree.

Comment: @Anderes, that could be! It won't be any infosec related however.